# HTML relative paths lead to 404 error within a navigation menu

Tags: html, css, path, relative-url

I have 6 files from my navigation menu that are connected to folders on my server inside the `public_html` main folder. I'm using `<nav>` as one of my tags since I'm connecting to an external css stylesheet that houses my menu's layout.

here's my menu in HTML:

```
<center>
    <nav>
        <ul id="mainMenu">
            <li><a href="public_html/Dome1/art.html">Art Dome</a></li>
            <li><a href="public_html/Dome2/music.html">Music Dome</a></li>
            <li><a href="public_html/Dome3/code.html">Dome Unknown</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/scrap+metal+near+me/@41.4745193,-81.7553814,14z/data=!3m1!4b1">Hunger Dome</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/special:Random">Education Dome</a></li>
            <li><a href="public_html/Dome6/yesno.html">Yes or No Dome</a></li>
            <!--yesno dome has green circle with yellow text saying "yes"-->
            <li><a href="public_html/Dome7/dontgo.html">Do Not Go Into This Dome!</a></li>
            <!--do not dome: red circle with text saying: you have entered into the wrong dome. Go back.-->
            <li><a href="public_html/Contact Dome/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</center>
```

As you can see, it's a little choppy, but I'd like to add relative paths such as: `Dome1/art.html` and so on. Any tips?

Comment: Where is this HTML file located on your server? Usually, I would only expect this markup to work if it is in the parent directory of `public_html`. :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, `<center></center>` isn't valid HTML anymore. Build a CSS class instead. It's not HTML5 compatible. That said, your paths shouldn't include the public_html folder. I rewrote your nav.

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="text-center">
      <ul id="mainMenu">
        <li><a href="dome1/art.html">Art Dome</a></li>
        <li><a href="dome2/music.html">Music Dome</a></li>
        <li><a href="dome3/code.html">Dome Unknown</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/scrap+metal+near+me/@41.4745193,-81.7553814,14z/data=!3m1!4b1">Hunger Dome</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/special:Random">Education Dome</a></li>
        <li><a href="dome6/yesno.html">Yes or No Dome</a></li>
        <!--yesno dome has green circle with yellow text saying "yes"-->
        <li><a href="dome7/dontgo.html">Do Not Go Into This Dome!</a></li>
        <!--do not dome: red circle with text saying: you have entered into the wrong dome. Go back.-->
        <li><a href="contact-dome/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```